# C++11 auto declaration with and without pointer declarator

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, variable-declaration

What's the difference between the types of `bar1` and `bar2`?

```
int foo = 10;
auto bar1 = &foo;
auto *bar2 = &foo;
```

If both `bar1` and `bar2` are `int*`, does it makes sense to write the pointer declarator (`*`) in the `bar2` declaration?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The declarations are exactly equivalent. `auto` works (almost) the same as [template type deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). Putting the star explicitly makes the code a bit easier to read, and makes the programmer aware that `bar2` is a pointer.

Answer (score 61):

Using `auto *` "documents intention". And `auto *p = expr;` can be deduced correctly only if `expr` returns pointer. Example:

```
int f();

auto q = f(); // OK

auto *p = f(); // error: unable to deduce 'auto*' from 'f()'
```

Comment: Yes, but next operator & is overloaded to return a notnull or const propagating smart pointer, and then auto * breaks.

Comment: I agree with documenting intention, and some of the assumptions made in client code about what it should be doing with the returned types might be less valid if you stop using it as a pointer for example. So this type of writing can avoid bugs during refactoring.

Answer (score 24):

There is a big difference when you use `const` qualifiers:

```
int i;

// Const pointer to non-const int
const auto ip1 = &i; // int *const
++ip1; // error
*ip1 = 1; // OK

// Non-const pointer to const int
const auto* ip2 = &i; // int const*
++ip2; // OK
*ip2 = 1; // error
```

Comment: This only depends on the placement of the `const` qualifier. If you explicitly want a constant pointer to non-constant memory, you can do: `auto* const ip3 = &i`. Then `ip3` and `ip1` behave exactly the same.

Comment: It helps when you read constness from right to left. `const auto *p` -> pointer to const auto. `const auto * const p` -> const pointer to const auto. `auto * const p` -> const pointer non const auto. I often even switch writing style to support that; in C++, `const int x` (x is an int which is const) is the same as `int const x` (x is a const x).

Answer (score 17):

In this specific example both `bar1` and `bar2` are the same. It's a matter of personal preference though I'd say that `bar2` is easier to read.

However, this does not hold true for references as seen in this [example](http://ideone.com/jH1g3Y):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int k = 10;
    int& foo = k;
    auto bar = foo; //value of foo is copied and loses reference qualifier!
    bar = 5; //foo / k won't be 5
    cout << "bar : " << bar << " foo : " << foo << " k : " << k << endl;
    auto& ref = foo;
    ref = 5; // foo / k will be 5
    cout << "bar : " << bar << " foo : " << foo << " k : " << k;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

As others said, they'll generate the same code.  The asterisk is line noise (and makes it harder to switch from raw pointers to smart pointers if, for example, `&foo` is ever replaced by `get_foo()`).  If you want to be explicit, then by all means, be explicit; but when you're using type inference, just let the compiler do its job.  Lack of asterisks does not imply that an object isn't a pointer.

Comment: I think the comment in parentheses deserves greater emphasis.  Even in the simple examples others have given, adding the `*` may make the code more readable, but can make maintenance more difficult.  I personally feel the primary benefit of `auto` is to ease maintenance, even more so than reducing typing or increasing readability.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't matter as far as the interpretation of the C++ code goes; you can write whatever you want. However, there is a question of style and readability: Generally, you should not hide pointer, reference and CV qualifiers, and perhaps even smart pointers, in type aliases, since it makes it harder for the reader to understand that that's what's going on. Type aliases should package the semantically relevant type content, whereas qualifiers and modifiers should remain visible. So prefer the following:

```
 using Foo = long_namespace::Foobrigation<other_namespace::Thing>;
 using MyFn = const X * (int, int);

 std::unique_ptr<Foo> MakeThatThing(MyFn & fn, int x)   // or "MyFn * fn"
 { 
     const auto * p = fn(x, -x);
     return p ? p->Create() : nullptr;
 }
```

And don't say:

```
using PFoo = std::unique_ptr<Foo>;   // just spell it out
using MyFn = int(&)(int, int);       // unnecessary; & is easy to spell
auto p = fn(x, -x);                  // Don't know that p is a pointer
```

Note also that reference qualifiers (unlike pointers) genuinely change the type of the variable that's being declared, so they're not optional:

```
X & f();
auto a = f();    // copy!
auto & b = f();  // b is the same as the return value of f()
```

Finally, adding explicit const pointer qualifications can help const-correctness. Consider the next example, in which a container contains pointers-to-mutable, but we only require const access. Just `auto *` would deduce a pointer to mutable, which we can avoid by saying `const` explicitly:

```
std::vector<X*> v = /* ... */;
for (const auto * p : v)
{
    observe(p->foo());   // no need for a mutable *p
}
```

Comment: As `MyFn` return type is `int`, `auto*p = fn(x, -x)` won't compile (thanks to `*`, else we should wait `p->Create()` for the error) :-) .

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes, I was using too few different entities. Fixed.