# Eliminate the "conversion to std::vector<int>::size_type to int" warning

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to eliminate warnings in my code and I am looking for an answer regarding those two:

```
1.   warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     for( auto i = 0; i < w.size(); i++ ) {
```

and

```
2. warning: conversion to ‘std::vector<int>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
         for ( int count = 0; count < w[i]; count++ )
```

The source code is below. A vector of ints is returned with some random numbers.

> ```
>  for( auto i = 0; i < w.size(); i++ ) {
> ```

```
     std::vector<int> random(std::vector<int>& w){


        std::vector<int> v;
        v.clear();

        std::random_device device;
        std::mt19937 generator(device());

        for( auto i = 0; i < w.size(); i++ ) {

            for ( int count = 0; count < w[i]; count++ )
                v.push_back(i);
        }

        std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), generator);

        return v;
    }
```

Optimal solution?

Comment: Relevant: [this answer and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34888054/253056).

Comment: I don't see how the second warning message could be generated by this code. There's no `size_type` in that line. Is this exactly the message you got or did you edit it?

Comment: No edits. Verbatim copy

Comment: Please post the full code you compiled then because this code won't cause that warning.

Comment: It is the full code. compiled with: -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wnoexcept -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-promo -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Wno-unused

Comment: Oh OK, I'm not used to so many warnings enabled. The second warning is rather confusing and is caused by the indexing in `w[i]`, not by the `count` variable as it seems to imply.

Comment: I don't understand why the question is closed. The second warning is not addressed in the linked question.

Comment: The second warning is caused by the same issue so fixing the first warning (e.g. by giving `i` the correct type) will also fix the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the first warning:

```
for( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < w.size(); i++ ) {
```

<strike>To fix the second warning:</strike>

```
for ( std::vector<int>::size_type count = 0; count < w[i]; count++ )
```

To make that a little less typing:

```
using index_t = std::vector<int>::size_type;
```

UPDATE: ha-ha (doh!), my mistake on the second warning.  It was caused by using i, not by count's type.

Comment: `count` is compared with `w[i]` which is an `int` so should also be an `int`.

Comment: where do I put that 2nd line? how does it help? it doesn't seem to be fixing my bug