# Why can't I eliminate this temporary variable in Eigen3?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I've run into trouble with a matrix-by-vector multiplication. Namely an innocous-looking expression always return a vector close to [1 0] while a similar-looking expression returns the correct result:

```
// version WITH temp var, correct
Eigen::Vector3d lcoord_eig(lcoord[0], lcoord[1], lcoord[2]);
auto lcoord2d = P3to2 * lcoord_eig;
std::cout << std::endl << lcoord2d << std::endl;

// version WITHOUT temp var, always [1 0]
auto lcoord2d_2 = P3to2 * Eigen::Vector3d(lcoord[0], lcoord[1], lcoord[2]);
std::cout << std::endl << lcoord2d_2 << std::endl;
```

where `P3to2` is a 2-by-3 matrix (`Eigen::MatrixXd`) and `lcoord` is the 3d vector type of some other library, with above code contained in a for-loop.

Some of the output (annotations by me):

```
-0.0036135
2.1684e-18   // correct

1
0   // [1 0], wrong

0.00209583
0.000388139   // correct

1
5.55112e-17   // [1 0], wrong

0.00148429
-0.000435008   // correct

1
5.55112e-17   // [1 0], wrong
```

This error took me a long time to spot, and I still don't understand what is going on that would cause the second version to behave like this. What mistake did I make?

---

Edit: This also happens for constant vectors, like `Eigen::Vector3d(.5,.5,.5)`

Comment: As a side note, `std::endl` != `\n`, but [`std::endl` == `\n` + `std::flush`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess (given you haven't included enough information in the question for anyone to reproduce) is that the use of `auto` is your problem. In your second case, the non working one, I suspect you are left with a dangling reference to the destroyed temporary `Vector3D`.

The [documentations](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html) says "do not use the auto keywords with Eigen's expressions, unless you are 100% sure about what you are doing".

If you use an explicit type your program will be clearer and more likely to work.

Comment: You're right, replacing `auto` with `Eigen::Vector2d` fixes the issue. I didn't know `auto` could be so dangerous!

Comment: @xjcl I'd guess Eigen uses expression templates, that's why

Comment: @Sopel Yes, Eigen uses expression templates indeed, which may bind a temporary to a `const` ref internally, and that binding ceases to be valid at the end of the statement. Use `.eval();` at the end of the expression if you want to force evaluation, like `auto lcoord2d = (P3to2 * lcoord_eig).eval();`. See e.g. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762002/3093378) for a bit more details.