# Lack of type information in structured bindings

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

I just learned about structured bindings in C++, but one thing I don't like about

```
auto [x, y] = some_func();
```

is that `auto` is hiding the types of `x` and `y`. I have to look up `some_func`'s declaration to know the types of `x` and `y`. Alternatively, I could write

```
T1 x;
T2 y;
std::tie(x, y) = some_func();
```

but this only works, if `x` and `y` are default constructible and not `const`. Is there a way to write

```
const auto [x, y] = some_func();
```

for non-default-constructible types of `x` and `y` in a way that makes the types of `x` and `y` visible? The compiler should preferably complain when I declare `x` and `y` as something incompatible with `some_func`'s return types, i.e. not `const auto /* T1, T2 */ [x, y] = some_func();`.

---

**Clarification.** Since the comments below my question seem to revolve around whether or not to use `&`, and some previous answers misunderstood my question as "which syntax to use to extract the returned pair's data type", I think I need to clarify my question.

Assume we have our code distributed in multiple files

```
//
// API.cpp
//
#include <utility>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo () {}
};

Foo foo;


class Bar {
private:
    Bar () {}
public:
    static Bar create () { return Bar(); }
};

Bar bar = Bar::create();


std::pair<int, bool> get_values () {
    return std::make_pair(73, true);
}

std::pair<Foo&, Bar&> get_objects () {
    return std::pair<Foo&, Bar&>(foo, bar);
}

//
// Program.cpp
//
int main (int, char**) {
    const auto [x, y] = get_values();
    const auto& [foo, bar] = get_objects();

    /* Do stuff with x, y, foo and bar */

    return 0;
}
```

At the time of writing this code the declarations of `get_values` and `get_objects` are fresh in my mind, so I know their return types. But when looking at `Program.cpp` one week later I barely remember the code in `main` let alone the data types of its variables or the return types of `get_values` and `get_objects`, so I need to open `API.cpp` and find `get_values` and `get_objects` to know their return types.

My question is whether there is a syntax to write the data types of the variables `x`, `y`, `foo` and `bar` in `main` into the structured binding? Preferably in a manner that allows the compiler to correct me, if I make mistakes, so no comments. Something along the lines of

```
int main (int, char**) {
    // Pseudo-Code
    [const int x, const bool y] = get_values();
    [const Foo& foo, const Bar& bar] = get_objects();
    /* Do stuff with x, y, foo and bar */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler complain... just `static_assert(std::is_same_v`?

Comment: `const auto& t = some_func(); const T1 x = std::get<0>(t); const T2 y = std::get<1>(t);` Doesn't get more explicit than that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think you placed the `&` at the wrong location.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Although that doesn't look like a structured binding anymore, I think that's the clearest way to retain the type information. Thank you :)

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik A reference to the local variable of a terminated function? I don't think it can work properly.

Comment: _"... I have to look up some_func's declaration ..."_ if you don't lookup the the declaration then how do you know `auto [x, y] = some_func();` is valid in the first place ?

Comment: @RichardCritten I think the point is when the code is read back. Still, it doesn't really matter here...

Comment: @digito_evo I'm not sure what you are talking about. What local variable in what terminated function?

Comment: @user202729 Exactly right

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Same thing I was saying early (t should not be reference, x and y should) Anyway (I can't find a duplicate and) this looks okay, you can post an answer.

Comment: The draw backs of using `auto` versus not is the same as [c++11 - Is there a downside to declaring variables with auto in C++? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758042/is-there-a-downside-to-declaring-variables-with-auto-in-c) (see also its linked questions.)

Comment: @digito_evo It might just be that the function returns references to other variables, not necessarily variables local to `some_func`.

Comment: @user202729 Can you show an example where my code as written wouldn't work? What would be the return type of `some_func()` that would make it not work?

Comment: @user202729 You may want to read about [temporary lifetime extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary). E.g. `int f() { return 42; } const int& x = f();` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Okay I thought it may be something like that; still, I think in either case you might want to add the `&` in the latter assignments

Comment: @user202729 I could, but that wouldn't be equivalent to the structured binding. Or rather, it would be equivalent to `const auto& [x, y] = some_func();` but not to `const auto [x, y] = some_func();` as in the original question. Also, it wouldn't work if the function doesn't in fact return `{T1, T2}` tuple, but a tuple of other types convertible to `T1` and `T2`, which could be the reason to want to spell out `T1` and `T2` explicitly in the first place.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Wouldn't your version copy `x` and `y` from `t` then? (unless T1 and T2 themselves are reference type?)

Comment: @user202729 Yes it would. So would `const auto [x, y] = some_func();`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik In your code the values are copied from the variable `t` to `x`, while for a structured binding it's only copied once from the function's return value (actually not because function return value is rvalue?), and `x` refers to the member of `t`. (still, there's no perfect solution, making the type of `x` `T1 (const) &` is different from `T1` in a few cases)

Comment: @user202729 My code doesn't copy the return value into `t`: `t` is a reference to it. So there's still only one copy.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik No, because the function returns a rvalue (or with RVO?) there would be zero copy in the structured binding case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no mechanism to state the types of "variables" in a structured binding declaration. If you want the type names to be visible, you have to forgo the convenience of structured binding declarations.

This is important because of how structured binding works. `x` and `y` aren't really variables per se. They're stand-ins for accessing the components of the object that the structured binding statement stored. They're components of the object that was captured by the declaration. There is only one actual variable: the unnamed variable that is `auto`-deduced. The names you declare are just components of that object.

Understanding this, now consider this statement: `int i = expr;` This code works so long as `expr` is something that can be *converted* to an `int`.

If you could put type names in structured binding declarations, people would have the *same* expectation. They would expect that if a function returns a `tuple<float, int>`, they could capture this in an `auto [int x, int y]`. But they *can't*, because the object being stored is a `tuple<float, int>`, and its first member is a `float`. The compiler would have to invent some new object that contains two `int`s and do a conversion.

But that's dangerous, particularly when dealing with return values that contain references. You can theoretically turn a `tuple<float&, int>` into a `tuple<int, int>`. But it wouldn't have the same *meaning*, since you cannot modify the object being referenced.

But again, users *expect* variable declarations to be able to do such conversions. Users rely on it all the time. Taking that power away would serve only to create confusion in the feature.

So the feature doesn't do it.

Comment: Very insightful. I thought about structured bindings like tuple unpacking from Python where the tuple's items are "unpacked" and distributed to the variables on the left side of the assignment. But if the "variables" in a structured binding are just aliases for the elements of a tuple that the compiler declares behind the scenes, then it is clear that I can't redeclare the variables.

Comment: "Taking that power away would serve only to create confusion in the feature." But the existing feature doesn't have that power anyway. IMO this is a minor consistency issue that most programmers would not notice or care about. In fact implicit conversions are generally discouraged anyway. Simply allowing type declarations without any conversion would be a net win for readability with no real downsides. I suspect the real reason it wasn't included was that nobody could agree on a non-ambiguous syntax so they just punted on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve structured binding and possible optimisations which comes with it, easiest way would be to put a comment denoting types. Obviously it would be bad if return types were to change: comment would become misleading. When writing types manually this would lead to a compile-time error.
To mimic this behavior, you can force a compile-time error manually:

```
#include <type_traits>

auto [x, y] = some_func();
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x), const my_type>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(y), some_other__type>);
```

It will show type information, force a compile-time error if type would ever happens to be not what you expect and even prevent undesired conversions from happening. No more accidentally assigning `long` to `int`.

Alternatively: use IDE which can display local variables and their type.

Answer (score 1):

You may do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

auto func( )
{
    int x = 5;
    double y = 5.5;

    std::cout << "Executing the func..." << '\n';

    return std::make_tuple<int, double>( std::move( x ), std::move( y ) );
}

int main()
{
    const auto returnVal = func( );
    const int& x = std::get<0>( returnVal );
    // const unsigned int& x = std::get<0>( returnVal ); // replace this with the upper one and 
                                                         // it will provoke a compile-time error

    const double& y = std::get<1>( returnVal );
    // const char& y = std::get<1>( returnVal ); // replace this with the upper one and 
                                                 // it will provoke a compile-time error

    static_assert( std::is_same_v< decltype( x ), decltype( std::get<0>( returnVal ) ) > &&
                   std::is_same_v< decltype( y ), decltype( std::get<1>( returnVal ) ) >, "Wrong types used" );

    std::cout << x << " " << y << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this can be a replacement for structured bindings. `x` and `y` are references to the returned value. And you do **explicitly** see their types when reading the source code. And in case you declare them with wrong types then the compiler will complain (e.g. `const char& y` instead of `const double& y` ).